# jQuery-ui Autocomplete show all values if no matching value found

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is it possible with jQuery Auto-complete, to make it so that if there are 'source:' values available, but they don't match what you are typing, then just show all the sources at once?

IE, given the following code, if I type in "pineapple", how do you show all the programming languages instead of none of them?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "JavaScript",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="tags" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) property with a custom function. The custom function shown below mimics autocomplete original behavior, searching for the typed text as substring inside available tags. If no match is found, all available tags are returned.

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "JavaScript",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
            var matchingTags = $.grep(availableTags, function(tag) {
                return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) >= 0;
            });
            response(matchingTags.length ? matchingTags : availableTags);
        }
    });
});​
```

## [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xP9ua/)

Comment: Awesome man.  There's a problem though, I don't know how to fix it either.  It says "tag.toLowerCase" is not a function.  Is tag being put in empty?  I'm so dumb at this...

Comment: See revised answer. The fiddle (original and current) seems to work for me.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to mess around with it.  My tags is an array of objects I think... hmm...

Comment: The example should work with minor changes, perhaps `tag.toLowerCase()` should be `tag.label.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Yes exactly, I tried tag.label and it failed.  My source is like this currently...

var resArr = [];
var resObj = new Object();
resObj.value = new Object();
resObj.value.val1 = x;
resObj.value.val2 = y;
resObj.label = z;
resObj.desc = a;
resArr.push(resObj);

Comment: Hah, I forgot to change the name of my array.  It works!  Thanks so much Salman for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Just write a custom `source` callback.

For example:

```
source: function(req, res){
    res(['w00t', 'yay']);
}
```

[See DOCs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

In your case (pseudocode):

```
source: function(req, res){
     //find `req` in array
     if not found:
     res(availableTags);
     else:
     res({subset of availableTags});
}
```